# Linear regression - Transforming the Independent Variable with the Dependent Variable

Tags: regression

I am examining the effect of the number of diseases someone has (independent variable - X) on the age at which they develop another disease (dependent variable - Y). X is measured up until the time they develop this other disease.

The hypothesis is that the bigger X is, the sicker the individual is in general/more prone to getting sick, and therefore the younger/sooner they will develop the new disease i.e. as X increases Y should decrease.

However, when I regress Y on X, I get a positive coefficient for X. This is obviously because the bigger Y is (i.e. the older they are), the more time they have had to accumulate other diseases (X is larger).

Is it valid to regress Y on X/Y to eliminate this unwanted effect? My thought was that the quantity X/Y reflects how intrinsically frail/prone to illness an individual is, adjusted for age, and therefore this should be related to the age at which they develop the new disease without the effect of time interfering.

However, I am not sure whether this is valid since then the independent variable then already contains/involves the dependent variable.

Comment: Can you isolate the disease you are interested in? More in general, I think that you should describe in more detail the nature of your variables. When you write "another disease (dependent variable - Y)," what is the exact meaning of "another disease?" Is it another specific disease? Or *any* other disease?